# Change header of response

Tags: reactjs, fetch

i have a react app create with create-react-app. i want to send request to another url:

```
fetch('anotherUrl')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res))
```

After that i've a cors problem. How to set middleware to null this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser addon to turn off cors. After you finish developing your app and put it online, cors won't be a problem. It is only problem when you run app in localhost.